# Weak derivative question

Tags: partial-differential-equations, weak-derivatives

[image]

I am confused of this example in Evans. Why is $|Du|$ calculated in this example?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because you need to show that $|Du|$ is in $L^p$.

Comment: Not to piggyback on this question, but why is the boundary in the second integral after performing integration by parts $\partial B(0,\epsilon)$ and not $\partial(U - B(0, \epsilon))$, is this because of the compact support that the test function has?

Comment: Because $\phi$ has compact support in $U$ and vanishes on the boundary of $U$.

Comment: Thank you for the answer! One more question: why do we want $\lvert Du\rvert$ in $L^1$ when we calculate the integral of the boundary therm?

Comment: In $L^p$, not in $L^1$. Is the definition of $W^{1,p}$.